# code coverage for pagination buttons

Tags: unit-test

I have written a code for pagination and for the test class other than the lines of buttons everything is getting covered.How can i get code coverage for the below lines of code?

```
public String firstPage {
        get 
        {
            return WP_Constants.FirstPageIcon;
        }
        private set;
    }

    // icon/image used for previous page link
    public String previousPage {
        get 
        {
            return WP_Constants.PreviousPageIcon;
        }
        private set;
    }

    // icon/image used for next page link
    public String nextPage {
        get 
        {
            return WP_Constants.NextPageIcon;
        }
        private set;
    }

    // icon/image used for last page link
    public String lastPage {
        get 
        {
            return WP_Constants.LastPageIcon;
        }
        private set;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your test code so far? Are you creating enough records in your test for the next/last button?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `c` is a reference to an instance of the class that has those properties defined, then in a test method:

```
System.assertEquals(WP_Constants.FirstPageIcon, c.firstPage);
System.assertEquals(WP_Constants.PreviousPageIcon, c.previousPage);
...
```

But apart from upping your coverage numbers these sort of assertions add little.